# Show that sum of the two closed sets in $\mathbb{R^2}$ is not closed.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Show that sum of the two closed sets in $\mathbb{R^2}$ is not always closed.

In $\mathbb{R^2}$, consider the sets $A =\{(x,y)\,\,:\,\, x>0,\,\,xy=1\}$ and $B =\{(x,y)\,\,:\,\, x>0,\,\,xy=-1\}$ which are closed, show that the sum A + B is not closed.
$$
A+B:=\{a+b : a \in A, b \in B\}
$$

To have better intuition, you can visualize the two sets as the following picture

[image]

Comment: ${}$Nice example!

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I revised the question. Show that the set $A+B$ is not closed.

Comment: What subset of the plane is $A+B$?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Both of your set specify $x > 0$ yet you plot points to the left of the $y$-axis.  Do you mean $x > 0$?

Comment: You are right. I revised it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the sequence $$(x_n)=\Big\{\Big(\frac{2}{n},0\Big)\Big\}_{1}^\infty=\Big\{\Big(\frac{1}{n},n\Big)+\Big(\frac{1}{n},-n\Big)\Big\}_{1}^\infty \in A+B$$ Here $$x_n \longrightarrow (0,0) \notin A+B$$
since the first coordinate of the element in $A+B$ is always positive .

So, $A+B$ is not closed!